# Find height $DH$ of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ determined by vectors $\vec{AB}=(1,0,-1)$, $\vec{AC}=(0,1,1)$, $\vec{AD}=(1,2,0)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

> We have to find the height $DH$ of the tetrahedron $ABCD$, and know that $\vec {AB}(1,0,-1), \vec{AC}(0,1,1), \vec{AD}(1,2,0)$.

I tried to calculate the mixed product and use the relation that says the volume of tetrahedron is $\tfrac16(\vec{AB}, \vec{AC}, \vec{AD})$. Finding the height from here gets complicated. I don't know how to find area of the base from here.

Comment: $$\text{area}\;\triangle ABC = \frac12\left|\,AB\times AC\,\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \geq 2$, below are two methods for finding the area of a triangle whose vertices *are* those points.  In both, if the origin is not already one of its vertices, it makes work much easier to first translate the triangle such that this is the case.

$\underline{\mathbf{Method \ \#1}}$:

Apply the formula $A = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\theta)$, which gives the area of the triangle having two side lengths $a$ and $b$ and angle $\theta$ between them (this data uniquely determines the triangle per [$SAS$ congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence)).  First, get the two side lengths from the Pythagorean theorem.  Now to get the angle, suppose the triangle has vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as sides.  We know of the dot product of two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$:

$$\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w} = ||\mathbf{v}|| ||\mathbf{w}|| \cos(\phi)$$

where $\phi$ is the angle between them.  Therefore, letting $\mathbf{A'}$ and $\mathbf{B'}$ denote the [normalizations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalizedVector.html) of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ respectively, $\theta = \arccos(\mathbf{A'} \cdot \mathbf{B'})$.  Note that one would *not even have to compute* this inverse cosine, because $\sin(\arccos(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

---

$\underline{\mathbf{Method \ \#2}}$:

A triangle is uniquely determined by the lengths of its sides per $SSS$ congruence.  It follows that a triangle's area is determined by the lengths of its sides, and this is conveyed in [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula):

> **Theorem**: If a triangle has side lengths $a, b, c$, then its area is equal to:
>   $$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
>   Where $s$ denotes the triangle's [*semiperimeter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperimeter), $\displaystyle \frac{a+b+c}{2}$.

You can find the area of the base in question using this formula, first finding the lengths needed using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: For higher dimensions, one can get the area of the triangle spanned by $a$ and $b$ via $$\tfrac12\sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2-(a\cdot b)^2}$$

Comment: Looks like I arrived at that very thing myself @Blue, though with $|a|^2|b|^2$ that'd be factored out of the radical due to the normalization.  I need this fact so infrequently that I just didn't have something off the top of my head